# Questions about subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

1、Firstly, my mysql version is 5.5.40

2、Following is the table data:

```
mysql> select * from student;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | lily      |
|  2 | lucy      |
|  3 | nacy      |
|  4 | hanmeimei |
+----+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from course;
+------------+--------+
| student_id | course |
+------------+--------+
|          1 | title  |
|          2 | title  |
|          3 | title  |
+------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

3、Why sql return this result set，what is subquery return? When I replace id to name，I get the same result.How it works?

```
mysql> select * from student where id in(select id from course);
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | lily      |
|  2 | lucy      |
|  3 | nacy      |
|  4 | hanmeimei |
+----+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from student where name in(select name from course);
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | lily      |
|  2 | lucy      |
|  3 | nacy      |
|  4 | hanmeimei |
+----+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

4、Here is my code to create tables and insert data:

```
CREATE TABLE `course` (
`student_id` int(11),
`course` varchar(20)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `course` VALUES ('1', 'title');
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES ('2', 'title');
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES ('3', 'title');

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11),
  `name` varchar(20)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ('1', 'lily');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ('2', 'lucy');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ('3', 'nacy');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ('4', 'hanmeimei');
```

Comment: I'm not sure that those queries are what generated the output.  Going by your table definitions above, the `course` table does not have either an `id` or `name` column.

Comment: There is no id in course

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html).

> A correlated subquery is a subquery that contains a reference to a
>   table that also appears in the outer query.

You can read the doc here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html

When you have no `id` field in your `course` table but you have table named `id` in parent table `student` it will look for parent field. No need to give a *field allias* when it have identic field each other, just like `JOIN`.

But when it have no `id` field either parent table, it will return error

> Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: So sql “select * from student where name in(select name from course)” equal "select * from student left join course on student.name=student.name" ?

Comment: @AnsionHe : it's equal to `select * from student where name in (select student.name from course)`

Comment: I can't understand what is sub_query "select student.name from course" return?

Comment: Yes,I have read the article,but I dont know what part the table course play in the sql. @Colour Dalnet

Comment: Try edit one of item in course and change it to one same name example `lily` and run this query `select * from student where id in
(select student_id from course where course = name)` , Hope you understand. G'luck.

Comment: `update course set course = 'lily' where student_id = 1;

select * from student where id in
(select student_id from course where course = name);`